# jenkins - pm2 restart all command in jenkins not updating the node-app for public

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to deploy node.js project on a server with the help of jenkins ,i have added GitHub web-hook and  every thing is working fine. **pm2 restart index.js** when i running this command from my user hamza its updating the content with new pull code but jenkins do command running successfully but not updating it even i tried su in my shell

```
    + ./script/deploy
su: must be run from a terminal
From https://github.com/hamza-younas94/node-app
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   a7e9a1a..188a395  master     -> origin/master
Updating a7e9a1a..188a395
Fast-forward
 index.js      | 2 +-
 script/deploy | 2 +-
 test/test.js  | 4 ++--
 3 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)
audited 190 packages in 1.706s
found 55 vulnerabilities (16 low, 19 moderate, 19 high, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Use --update-env to update environment variables
[PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [index.js](ids: 0)
[PM2] [index](0) ✓
┌──────────┬────┬─────────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬───────────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ version │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem       │ user    │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼───────────┼─────────┼──────────┤
│ index    │ 0  │ 0.0.2   │ fork │ 10159 │ online │ 138     │ 0s     │ 0%  │ 22.0 MB   │ jenkins │ disabled │
└──────────┴────┴─────────┴──────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴───────────┴─────────┴──────────┘
 Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
Finished: SUCCESS
```

my ubtunu terminal output of pm2 command which working fine

```
┌──────────┬────┬─────────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬───────────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ version │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem       │ user    │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼───────────┼─────────┼──────────┤
│ index    │ 0  │ 0.0.2   │ fork │ 10159 │ online │ 25     │ 0s     │ 0%  │ 22.0 MB   │ hamza │ disabled │
└──────────┴────┴─────────┴──────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴───────────┴─────────┴──────────┘
```

my deploy shell code:

```
#!/bin/sh 
su - hamza
cd /home/hamza/node-app
git pull origin master
npm install --production
pm2 restart index.js
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

well i did it via shell in my shell i am connecting other user via ssh.

- login in jenkins user generated ssh key
- add the key in authorized_keys
- wrote a shell which connection otheruser@my_ip_add and wrote command which i need

Why i have to do this?
Because pm2 restart all was working but working as jenkins user and you can see it in my question, when i was restart it with my otheruser which started it was working fine.

PS: may be pm2 require same user/session for doing activity